# Flask url_for results in escape_chars http_405

Tags: flask

I have searched and read many similar posts, but my problem has different behavior than any I've found.

I have a super simple flask app (below).  All it does is present test.html page with 2 buttons to call-back to a python def.

1. Test1 button has hard-coded form action="/test".

   - Works
2. Test2 button has form action="{{ url_for('test') }}"

   - Fails with: > POST /%7B%7B%20url_for('test')%20%7D%7D HTTP/1.1" 405 -
   - Method not allowed

What might be the problem?
Are the escape characters the problem?  If so, how do I prevent them?

test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from flask import Flask, request, send_file
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='', static_folder='')

@app.route('/')
def FooTest():
  return app.send_static_file('test.html')

@app.route("/test", methods=["GET","POST"])
def test():
  print("Got Callback:")
  return "Click"

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug=True)
```

test.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
   <form method="post" action="/test">
       <button type="submit"> Test1</button/>
   </form>
   <form method="post" action="{{ url_for('test') }}">
       <button type="submit"> Test2</button/>
   </form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your test.html is a Jinja2 template which would be processed by calling `render_template` to create the desired HTML. You return the template as is, therefore the browser attempts to call `http://localhost:5000/{{ url_for('test') }}` which does not exist. Change `FooTest` like this (you might have to adjust the file path):

```
from flask import render_template

@app.route('/')
def FooTest():
  return render_template('test.html')
```

Comment: Ah, interesting.  I need to serve up the html file from my static location.  Can url_for work from static?  Or, is that a bad thing?

Comment: I have started working with Flask only recently myself and cannot assess if that violates best practices. What I can say is that Jinja2 is a generic templating engine not specific to HTML, thus also useful for rendering JSON or other content so I don't think this should keep you from trying that out. I would argue that a location for static content is not the best location for templates however.